# C/C++ script optimization

Tags: c++, c, optimization, functional-programming, compiler-optimization

I have 3 matrices, `gX`, `gY` and `gNorm`, and one for loop like this:

```
for(y=1; y<n-1; y++){
      int base = y*this->_nxsIn;
      for(x=1; x<n-1; x++){ 
          i1 = base + x;
          i2 = i1 + 1;
          i3 = i1 + n;
          den = ( (gX[i1]+gY[i1])*gNorm[i1] - gX[i2]*gNorm[i2] - gY[i3]*gNorm[i3];
}
```

If I extract the products `gX * gNorm` and `gY * gNorm` in this way:

```
for(y=0; y<n; y++){
      int base = y*n;
      for(x=0; x<n; x++){
           i = base + x;
          GxGnorm[i] = gX[i]*gNorm[i];
       }
   }

//Gy * GNorm

for(y=0; y<n; y++){
     int base = y*n;
     for(x=0; x<n; x++){
          i = base + x;
         GyGnorm[i] = gY[i]*gNorm[i];
      }
}


for(y=1; y<this->_nysIn-1; y++){
      int base = y*this->_nxsIn;
      for(x=1; x<this->_nxsIn-1; x++){  
      i1 = base + x;
      i2 = i1 + 1;
      i3 = i1 + n;

      i1Sum = GxGnorm[i1] + GyGnorm[i1];         //(gX[i1]+gY[i1])*gNorm[i1];
      float sum1 = GxGnorm[i2] + GyGnorm[i3];    //gX[i2]*gNorm[i2];

     }
}
```

Can I get improvements in computation time?

If no, why?

Comment: Yes, but the questions is another. Why the second script  might be better than the first

Answer (score 0):

Well, both scripts have the same asymptotic time, O(n^2), which is bad if you have a substantial data set.

As you have repetitions of the nested loops in your second script, you are actually increasing the constant factor. Add to that the costs of creating the extra arrays.

Other than these both scripts are quite similar. So, the second script might actually be slower.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Another question: from the point of view of the cache (general case), they have the same behavior?